# Python Function in Javascript Package

Tags: javascript, python, package

I have a python file that holds many subsidiary methods and one essential function calling those subsidiary functions. The essential function takes a string as input and spits out a 2D array. However, I need to use it in the web development project. How do I pass on the user-input string to the python file via JS and then get the output in a JSON format back from the python file?

python file's essential function

```
def foo(str, num):

    bar = doSomething(temp, str)
 
    raw_output = doAction(bar)

    final_output= doRefining(raw_output[:num], 10)
    
    return final_output
```

What I tried in index.js

```
const getRes = () => {
    
    const child_process = require('child_process');
    child_process.spawn('python', ['pythonFile.py']);
    

    process.stdout.on('data',function(response){
        var output = response;
        return output;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work, with only one important modification: instead of doing `return output`, you should use it. I usually do that by creating a `buffer` variable outside the callback's scope, and appending the data to it as it arrives.
Then, on the `close` event, you can use the data, or return it using a promise/callback.

An example:

```js
const child_process = require('child_process');

const getRes = callback => {
    child_process.spawn('python', ['pythonFile.py']);
    
    let result = '';

    process.stdout.on('data', data => {
        result += data;
    });
    process.on('close', () => {
        callback(result);
    });
}

// Example usage:
getRes(result => {
    console.log('Output:', result);
});
```